# Why am I prohibited from posting answers just because I have not asked questions?

Tags: discussion, answers

Why am I prohibited from posting answers just because I have not asked questions?

BTW in general Stack Overflow is very useful to me when I look for answers. I just want to return the favor. A number of times, I have been in a very generous mood, willing to write (and revise for clarity) an answer, only to be stymied by the policy at hand.

Comment: What is the error message you are getting?

Comment: @Chris it doesn't matter if the OP is an anonymous user for SO, only MSO.

Comment: Ah, thanks for bringing that to my attention. Could you provide a link to the question you are trying to answer, @user553593?

Comment: `BTW in general Stack Overflow is very useful to me when I look for answers.` You should vote up those helpful answers, from your profile it appears you have done exactly nothing since signing up.  Have you actually *attempted* to answer?

Answer (score 15):

According to [/privileges/create-posts](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/create-posts), this is simply not true — anyone can post an answer.

> #### What is asking and answering questions?
>
> The most basic privilege of all -- the right to ask a question, and the right to contribute an answer. This is generally available to everyone, regardless of reputation level.

Comment: Agreed. I've answered several questions without posting any questions.

Comment: +1, I have no questions on SO but I'm able to answer.

Answer (score 6):

You can't leave *comments* on Stack Overflow unless you have at least 50 reputation. Anyone can post answers.  Please note the [privileges page (on Meta)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges) and [similarly on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges).

Comment: Exactly right. *Comments are not answers.*

Answer (score 4):

Given the [user's reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/users/553593/user553593) on Stack Overflow, I suspect that what may actually be going on is that as an anonymous user, I believe you can't post an answer?  Hence, if you login first, then yes you can post an answer.  But if you stay anonymous, then you'll see (**but only here on Meta** -- Note Matt Ball's comments below about how Stack Overflow allows anonymous answers):

[image: Must log in first...]

Comment: You can still answer as an anonymous user. Just log out of your SO account, and look at any question that hasn't been protected.

Comment: @Matt, I took a screen shot of this question?  I was in chrome where I'm not logged in?

Comment: Meta SO is different from regular SO. Do it on the full site, you'll see.

Comment: hehe.  I stand thus rebuked.  You are correct.  I'll update to reflect.

Answer (score 2):

Everyone is flaming the question, but he may actually still be correct.

People with 15k Reputation can lock a question and prevent people (new users) from answering on it.

Source: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/

> 15000  Protect questions to prevent answers by new users

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation

Comment: That rarely ever happens though.  Almost any new question that is asked now will not be protected. (~99.999%)

Comment: Yeah I agree. I'm just pointing out that it is still a possibility. If I could remember that Sherlock Holme's quote I would say it :D (Or was it Tuvok??)